# Hey Guys, I'm currently working with flask and got an error

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, typeerror

I created a program for database and I am getting this error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I have created 2 separate files l:

- Demo1.py
- model.py

The code inside the main file `(Demo1.py)`:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"]) 

def home():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("Index.html", message="Bonjour!")
    else:
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        if username == "Tom" and password == "sau123":
            message= model.show_color("Tom")
            return render_template("football.html", message=message)
        else:
            error_message="Failed, Try Again"
            return render_template("Index.html", message=error_message )


@app.route("/football", methods=["GET"])

def football():
    return render_template("football.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Now, Let me mention the code inside of the `model.py`:

```
import sqlite3

def show_color(username):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("flask.db", check_same_thread=False)
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT color FROM users WHERE username="{username}" ORDER BY pk DESC;""".format(username=username))
    color = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    message= "{username}/' favorite color is {color}.".format(username=username, color=color)
    return message
```

The Image which shows the error is below:
[image]

I don't understand why am I getting this error.

Comment: Check if the username and the corresponding color exists in the database. Basically after executing that line  in `show_color`, it's saying that the corresponding entry doesn't exist.

Comment: Is the form passing back an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchone()` returns probably `None` (meaning the SELECT has no result).

To verify you can modify `show_color` :

```
def show_color(username):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("flask.db", check_same_thread=False)
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT color FROM users WHERE username="{username}" ORDER BY pk DESC;""".format(username=username))
    
    first_result = cursor.fetchone()
    if first_result  is None:
        message= "{username} doesn't have any favorite color.".format(username=username)
    else:
        color = first_result[0] 
        # connection.commit() # I do not understand this commit without any modification
        message= "{username}/' favorite color is {color}.".format(username=username, color=color)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()


    return message
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone